# Is there a way to secure credential while using OPENROWSET in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I want to secure username and password while using OPENROWSET without mention username and password as explicit. This is my current query

```
SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET('SQLNCLI', 'DRIVER={SQL Server}; SERVER=Name\instance; UID=username;PWD=password', test.dbo.STG)
```

From this query I want to hide username and password. There's is a way?

Comment: Create a linked server and use openquery